# MKMapView crashes when dismissing view when overylaying tiles ios7

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mktileoverlay

So I have a tableview with different locations that modally presents another view controller with a mapview. I add custom tiles on top of the map, but if i dismiss the view controller while the mapview is still loading tiles and open up a different location my app crashes. This only happens when i uncomment the addOverlay tiles method.

```
MKTileOverlay *tiles = [[MKTileOverlay alloc] initWithURLTemplate:@"http://tileurl.com/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"];
[tiles setCanReplaceMapContent:YES];
[_mapView addOverlay:tiles level:MKOverlayLevelAboveLabels];
```

Any suggestions as to why this is happening?

Comment: What is the crash and/or stack trace?

Comment: The log doesnt show anything, i just get a EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0xdefe) or sometimes it takes me to main function and has a similar error.

Comment: Sometimes disabling the exception breakpoint will provide a stack trace with more information.  Without a message or stack trace it is impossible to say what is happening.  Do you remove the tiles overlay when you dismiss the view controller?

Comment: How do i disable the exception breakpoint? And no i do not remove the tiles overlay when i dismiss it, i figured the mapview would handle that on its own when it deallocs

Comment: After removing the tiles in viewWillDisappear, i dont seem to be running into any crashes. Thanks for the suggestion!